# Internal server error on CkanAPI with datastore_search_sql

Tags: datastore, ckan

I'm tryin to set up the `datastore_search_sql` feature to CkanAPI, and when I try to query on the frontend i get en Internal Server Error message.

I've added to mi `config.ini` file the following lines and nothing changes:

`ckan.datastore.sqlsearch.enabled = true`
  `ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_search_sql=`

Comment: Hoping you can add a bit more info... what version of CKAN are you using? Were you following these docs to add and configure the datastore (see link below)? If you have followed these then the datastore api should be good to go, the `sqlsearch.enabled` is true by default.  https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/datastore.html#setting-up-the-datastore

Comment: The ckan_version it's "2.7.4". I'm using Ckan app developed by the government, the oficial repo is here → https://github.com/datosgobar/portal-andino . I understand that the do the correct set up for the DataStore

Comment: What do your server logs say? I've tested with a basic install of CKAN and datastore locally following the docs and everything seems OK on my end. I didn't have to adjust anything in my `development.ini` beyond what the docs mention in their setup instructions.  Here's an example of the format I used to do a basic test `http://site-url.com/api/action/datastore_search_sql?sql=SELECT * from "resource_id"`. Hope this helps give you some clues and you get it working.